# Rails 3: Wrapping as_json response with additional lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I was very happy to learn of as_json to make my code DRY. And I've added the following to a model:

```
class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :component_types

  def as_json(parameter)
    {:name => self.name,
     :description => self.description,
     :children => self.componentTypes}
  end
end
```

This is great. The only thing is that for my client side application, I need to wrap the response I get into this format, (where "items" contains what is created by as_json):

```
{
  "identifier": "name",
  "label": "name",
  "items": 
    [
      {
        "name": "myName1",
        "description": "myDesc1",
        "children":[]
      },
      {
        "name": "myName2",
        "description": "myDesc2",
        "children":[]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what seems to be DIY :) what is `myModelsChildren`?

Comment: updated the question to show the proper names... I wanted to keep it generic. But there you are. It's a one to many relationship between `product_type` (model shown above) and `component_type`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of limitations to overriding `as_json`, and your issue is one of them. I'd suggest having a look at the [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) gem as I think it will help you reach your goal.

Comment: That looks cool, but I'm actually so close with the `as_json`, that I'd rather find a simple way to wrap it without adding more gems to the system.